# React Native - Modal is showing on a different FlatList screen

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, modal-dialog, react-native-flatlist

I'am having trouble with modal because I have some in a "Datails screen" with Flatlist and it is working fine, actually. But the thing is, before navigating to my "Datails screen" the user will first see the "Category screen", and here is where the problem. Because I didn't type any modal at my "Category screen", but whenever I click on any button in there a modal is showing, it looks very tricky for me.

Here is my code

**Details.js** (this is the only screen where I want to display my modal)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableHighlight, View,
StyleSheet, Platform, FlatList, AppRegistry,
TouchableOpacity, RefreshControl, Dimensions, Modal
} from 'react-native';

export default class Details extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: ''
    };

    constructor()
    {
        super ()
        this.state = {
            showModal: true
        }
    }

    state = {
        data: [],
        refreshing: false
    };


    fetchData = async() => {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        const response_Cat = await fetch('http://192.168.254.100:3307/categories/' + params.id);
        const category_Cat = await response_Cat.json();
        this.setState({data: category_Cat});
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    };

    _onRefresh() {
        this.setState({ refreshing: true });
        this.fetchData().then(() => {
            this.setState({ refreshing: false })
        });
    };

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
      return (
          <View style = { styles.container }>
              <FlatList
                data = { this.state.data }
                renderItem = {({ item }) =>
                    <TouchableOpacity style = { styles.buttonContainer }>
                        <Text style = { styles.buttonText }
                        onPress = { () => { this.setState({showModal:true}) } }>{ item.menu_desc } { item.menu_price }</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                /*refreshControl = {
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing = { this.state.refreshing }
                        onRefresh = { this._onRefresh.bind(this) }
                    />
                }*/
              />

            <View>
            <Modal
                onRequestClose={() => console.warn('no warning')}
                visible={this.state.showModal}
            >
                <TouchableOpacity style = { styles.buttonContainer }>
                    <Text style = { styles.buttonText }
                    onPress = { () => { this.setState({ showModal:false }) } }>Hello</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity> 
            </Modal>
            </View>

          </View>
      );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    pageName:{
        margin:10,fontWeight:'bold',
        color:'#000', textAlign:'center'
    },
    productBox:{
        padding:5,margin:10,borderColor:'orange',borderBottomWidth:1
    },
    price:{
        padding:5, color:'orange',fontWeight:'bold',textAlign:'center'
    },
    proName:{
        padding:5,color:'blue',textAlign:'center'
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#f7c744',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        borderRadius: 30,
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    buttonText: {
        textAlign: "center",
        color: 'rgb(32, 53, 70)',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 18
    },
    modalView: {
        backgroundColor: "#aaa",
        height: 150,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    closeText: {
        backgroundColor: '#333',
        color: '#bbb',
        padding: 5,
        margin: 20
    }
})

//AppRegistry.registerComponent('Details', () => Details);
```

**categories.js** (this is the page where I don't type any modal code, I guess)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableHighlight, View,
StyleSheet, Platform, FlatList, AppRegistry,
TouchableOpacity, RefreshControl
} from 'react-native';

export default class Categories extends Component {    
    state = {
        data: [],
        refreshing: false
    };

    fetchData = async() => {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        const response_Cat = await fetch('http://192.168.254.100:3307/categories/');
        const category_Cat = await response_Cat.json();
        this.setState({data: category_Cat});
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    };

    _onRefresh() {
        this.setState({ refreshing: true });
        this.fetchData().then(() => {
            this.setState({ refreshing: false })
        });
    }

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
      return (
          <View style = { styles.container }>
              <FlatList
                data = { this.state.data }
                renderItem = {({ item }) =>
                    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}
                        onPress = { () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', { id: item.cat_id }) }>{ item.cat_name }</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

                refreshControl = {
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing = { this.state.refreshing }
                        onRefresh = { this._onRefresh.bind(this) }
                    />
                }
              />
          </View>
      );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    pageName:{
        margin:10,fontWeight:'bold',
        color:'#000', textAlign:'center'
    },
    productBox:{
        padding:5,margin:10,borderColor:'orange',borderBottomWidth:1
    },
    price:{
        padding:5, color:'orange',fontWeight:'bold',textAlign:'center'
    },
    proName:{
        padding:5,color:'blue',textAlign:'center'
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#f7c744',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        borderRadius: 30,
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    buttonText: {
        textAlign: "center",
        color: 'rgb(32, 53, 70)',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 18
    },

})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Categories', () => Categories);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `details.js` you kept `showModal: true` in constructor itself.

Change it to false, and make it true whenever you want to show a modal.

I guess you should make it true after you have successfully fetched data. i.e keep it in `fetchData()`

```
 this.setState({data: category_Cat, showModal:true});
```

Comment: Thank you hehehe I didn't notice that. :)